# like button publish: name user liked index of/ on app name

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, metatag

i have a problem with like button: if clicked, it shows on timeline this post:

{name user} liked index of/ on {app name} with correct description and thumbnail

i put these metatag

```
<meta name="description" content="Ho appena creato la mia storia con ''Lettere d'amore'' di Goldenpoint. Fallo anche tu e avrai subito un buono sconto del 10% da utilizzare in tutti i negozi goldenpoint e sullo shop on line" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $urlThumb; ?>" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Goldenpoint Lettere d&#039;amore" />
<meta property="og:type" content="game" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";?>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Goldenpoint Lettere d&#039;amore" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

and like button is:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=404791622949241";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://apps.facebook.com/lettereamore/" data-    send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

with debugger i see a weird thing: if i type the website url, everything is perfect, but if i do a test by using the url of the facebook app, it returns index of

how i can fix this?
thank you